# About shorthand \frac

Tags: macros, fractions

It is possible to write `\frac 2 4` or `\frac \pi 4`  to get `2/4` and `\pi/4`, respectively.

However, it is not possible to write `\frac \sqrt{2} 2` to get `\sqrt{2}/2`.

Are there consistent rules on how to write shorthand `\frac`?

Comment: Note that this is nothing to do with `\frac` _per se_: you will see the same with almost any commands where you provide single tokens as mandatory arguments.

Comment: Enclose the `\sqrt{2}` with  `{}` to make it a single token.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The command `\frac` has two mandatory arguments. So you can they the first two tokens are the arguments (or simple the first two groups).

`\frac \sqrt{2} 2` fails because `\sqrt` is the first token, `{2}` the second one.