# Write in an easy way $\frac{a}{b}$. Shortcuts to output the fractions

Tags: fractions

Is there any way to create automatically fractions without writing every time **\frac{a}{b}**. Is there any easy method to write this?

Comment: What editor do you use? You may well have/set up a shortcut in it.

Comment: I usually use Texnic Center.

Comment: not sure what you could do really, you presumably have to type a and b, the `{}` you can omit if they are a single letter `\frac12` is a half, you could do `\let\f\frac` then `\f12` would be a half and it's hard to get a lot fewer keystrokes than that.

Comment: Related: [Is it wrong to use `\frac1{}`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41019/5764); [About shorthand `\frac`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66360/5764)

Comment: The objective "any way to create automatically fractions" is phrased rather vaguely. Please tell us what you have in mind.

Comment: In VI editor (VIM)  you use `/  Then proceed to fill up the fields (numerator and denominator)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it wrong to use \frac1{}?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41019/is-it-wrong-to-use-frac1)

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/446825/212679) great AHK script, written by the user @scavi, which makes writing in LateX much more comfortable and agile. It autocompletes the tedious \frac{}{} by just typing \fra and pressing the tab key, as well as including many other features.

Answer (score 0):

If you are an Emacs user, you can use the quick calc mode in your latex document.
calc must be configured (see the calc menu bar): Fraction mode, symbolic mode, no simplification mode, LaTeX language mode.

If it's set up correctly, you can just call Quick Calculation Mode, type your formula, and paste the output into your latex document.
for example, you type C-x * q to invoke quick calc mode and type

```
  (-b + sqrt (b ^ 2-4 ac)) / (2 a)
```

the output is

```
  \ frac {-b + \ sqrt {b ^ 2-4 ac}} {2 a}
```

An alternative is the embedded calc mode: you type your formula directly into your latex document and call this mode which performs the conversion.